# How to convert existing secretkey to CryptoKeypair to use with new @solana/web3.js?

Tags: web3.js

With the current version of `@solana/web3.js`, we can recreate a keypair from a saved secretkey:

```
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey)
```

The new version of `@solana/web3.js` has a `generateKeyPair()` function that returns a `CryptoKeyPair`.

```
const keypair = await generateKeyPair();
```

```
interface CryptoKeyPair {
    privateKey: CryptoKey;
    publicKey: CryptoKey;
}
```

How do you convert a secretkey to a `CryptoKeyPair` that can be used with the new version of `@solana/web3.js`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks [Buffalo Joe](https://twitter.com/realbuffalojoe) for the help!

There is a [`fromLegacyKeypair` helper function](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/compat/src/keypair.ts), which is part of a lib called `@solana/compat`.

**Install the latest version** with `npm i @solana/compat@experimental`

```
import { fromLegacyKeypair } from "@solana/compat";
import { Keypair } from "@solana/web3.js";

const sender = new Keypair();

const cryptoKeyPair = await fromLegacyKeypair(sender);
console.log(cryptoKeyPair);
```

As Serban mentioned in the previous comment, `fromLegacyKeypair` [uses the `importKey` method](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/packages/compat/src/keypair.ts)

It doesn't seem there is currently a helper function to convert raw bytes directly to a `CryptoKeypair`, but the `fromLegacyKeypair` helper function can be used as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

`CryptoKeyPair` is an object native to browsers that is part of the [`Web Crypto API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

Solana uses `Ed25519`, which is not supported on all browsers yet, but the Solana team have offered a polyfill for it. You can find it [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/tree/master/packages/webcrypto-ed25519-polyfill) along with an example.

To import an existing key, create an `Uint8Array` of your secret key and use the [importKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) method.

Comment: This is a link-only answer - answers on Stack Exchange are generally expected to include working code.